# Installing a dependent resource from PS Gallery

Tags: powershell, dsc

How do I tell DSC that a resource/module from OneGet/Package Management needs installing, first?

Do I just use a Script Resource and configure `PowerShellGet` and then manually call `Install-Module`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use powershell remoting and install the modules beforehand.

or

you could use a script resource

or

use this module from github
[powershellmodule](https://github.com/davidobrien1985/DscResources/tree/master/PowerShellModule)

if you have a pull server you can use the github module centrally otherwise when using push you will have to copy the github module referenced above to all target systems but then it is a one time process at least for installing modules from the gallery.

Comment: I can't install modules and use their resources in the same configuration, because Import-DscResource validation fails. I had to apply multiple DSC configurations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848209/dsc-push-mode-best-way-to-copy-dsc-resources/48324001#48324001

Answer (score 1):

You can use the packagemanagement provider resource available here in order to install the required packages https://github.com/PowerShell/PackageManagementProviderResource

Comment: great...didnt know this was available!